# spring-data-elasticsearch searching over multiple indices

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

i have a searchfield on my page and this searchfield should search over more than one indice.
I can search for one indice without a problem, like described in the documentation of spring-data-elasticsearch.

But if i search, as example for "Foo", i want to have the following list as result ordered by relevance:

```
{ title: "Foo" } -> Entity: Sample
{ name: "FooTest" } -> Entity: Test
{ title: "FooSample2" } -> Entity: Sample
// ...and so on
// The entities are not part of the same parent. So, they are complete different.
```

For this i couldn't find anything in documentation that would help me.

can anybody help?

**EDIT:**

```
final SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                .withIndices("game-index", "lets-play-index", "video-index", "genre-index", "platform-index", "user-index")
                .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 10))
                .build();

            // when
            final Page<SearchResult> sampleEntities = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery, SearchResult.class, new SearchResultMapper() {

                @Override
                public <T> FacetedPage<T> mapResults(
                                                        final SearchResponse response,
                                                        final Class<T> clazz,
                                                        final Pageable pageable) {
                    LoggerUtil.get(this.getClass())
                        .debug(response.toString());
                    LoggerUtil.get(this.getClass())
                        .debug(response.getHits()
                            .toString());
                    LoggerUtil.get(this.getClass())
                        .debug("TotalHits: " + response.getHits()
                            .totalHits());

                    final long totalHits = response.getHits()
                        .totalHits();
                    final List<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();
                    for (final SearchHit hit : response.getHits()) {
                        LoggerUtil.get(this.getClass())
                            .debug(hit.sourceAsString());
                        if (hit != null) {
                            final T result = null;
                            /*
                             * if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(hit.sourceAsString()))
                             * { result = mapEntity(hit.sourceAsString(),
                             * clazz); } else { result =
                             * mapEntity(hit.getFields() .values(), clazz); }
                             */
                            // setPersistentEntityId(result, hit.getId(),
                            // clazz);
                            results.add(result);
                        }
                    }
                    final List<FacetResult> facets = new ArrayList<FacetResult>();
                    if (response.getFacets() != null) {
                        for (final Facet facet : response.getFacets()) {
                            final FacetResult facetResult = DefaultFacetMapper.parse(facet);
                            if (facetResult != null) {
                                facets.add(facetResult);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return new FacetedPageImpl<T>(results, pageable, totalHits, facets);
                }

            });
```

the response inside of SearchResultMapper is the follwing:

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 30,
    "successful" : 30,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

if i do a simple search with this:

```
final Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);

            final SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(getQueryBuilderForQuery(query))
                .build();
            final List<?> results = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, clazz);
```

it works and i get many results. that means my index is working.

i have definitly no idea what i can do. thanks a lot.

Comment: if i am reading you right then you want to search across multiple indices, this is not yet supported but not a big deal, can you please create JIRA at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES/ ? and that will be pushed to next iteration.

Comment: Ticket created: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-77

Comment: can you give me some "quick" solution or direction what i have to use to get the resultlist that i need?

Comment: have a look at answer below, sorry for the confusion. its already supported !

Answer (score 5):

Sorry this is already supported

try below code, it should be working...

however below code is for where you have same structure in Entity and elasticsearch document

```
    @Test
    public void shouldTestResultsAcrossMultipleIndices() {
    // given
    String documentId1 = randomNumeric(5);
    SampleEntity sampleEntity1 = new SampleEntityBuilder(documentId1).message("some message")
            .version(System.currentTimeMillis()).build();

    IndexQuery indexQuery1 = new IndexQueryBuilder().withId(sampleEntity1.getId())
            .withIndexName("test-index-1")
            .withObject(sampleEntity1)
            .build();

    String documentId2 = randomNumeric(5);
    SampleEntity sampleEntity2 = new SampleEntityBuilder(documentId2).message("some test message")
            .version(System.currentTimeMillis()).build();

    IndexQuery indexQuery2 = new IndexQueryBuilder().withId(sampleEntity2.getId())
            .withIndexName("test-index-2")
            .withObject(sampleEntity2)
            .build();

    elasticsearchTemplate.bulkIndex(Arrays.asList(indexQuery1, indexQuery2));
    elasticsearchTemplate.refresh("test-index-1", true);
    elasticsearchTemplate.refresh("test-index-2", true);

    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
            .withIndices("test-index-1", "test-index-2")
            .build();
    // when
    List<SampleEntity> sampleEntities = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, SampleEntity.class);
    // then
    assertThat(sampleEntities.size(), is(equalTo(2)));
}
```

if you have different structure in the index then you can use below method of elasticsearchTemplate

```
  Page<T> queryForPage(SearchQuery query, Class<T> clazz, SearchResultMapper mapper);
```

still confused ?
happy to help
:-)